# NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData does not work in Swift 3 iOS

Tags: ios, swift, encode, dealloc, nskeyedarchiver

When try to encode my custom object in iOS swift get this error from Xcode 8.3

> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800166fe80
>   *** -[NSKeyedArchiver dealloc]: warning: NSKeyedArchiver deallocated without having had -finishEncoding called on it.

And my code like this:

import UIKit
import Foundation

```
class Place: NSObject {

    func setCustomObject(CustomObject obj:Any,Key key:String) {

        let encodedObject : Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: obj)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedObject, forKey: key)

    }
}
```

Comment: Does your `CustomObject` conform to `NSCoding` protocol?

Comment: No @njuri , is need?

Comment: Yes, will describe in answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example how to make an object to conform to `NSCoding`. Basically you need to provide implementation of two methods - `required convenience init?(coder decoder: NSCoder)` and `encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)`

```
class Book: NSObject, NSCoding {
  var title: String?
  var pageCount: Int?

  // Memberwise initializer
  init(title: String,pageCount: Int) {
   self.title = title
   self.pageCount = pageCount
  }

  // MARK: NSCoding


  // Here you will try to initialize an object from archve using keys you did set in `encode` method.
  required convenience init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    guard let title = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "title") as? String else { return nil }

    self.init(title: title, pageCount: decoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "pageCount"))
  }

  // Here you need to set properties to specific keys in archive
  func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(self.title, forKey: "title")
    aCoder.encodeCInt(Int32(self.pageCount), forKey: "pageCount")
  }
}
```

Also I would recommend changing your `setCustomObject` method to this:

```
func setCustomObject(obj:NSCoding, key:String) {
  let encodedObject : Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: obj)
  UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedObject, forKey: key)
}
```

This way compiler prevent you passing `NSKeyedArchiver` an object that does not conform to `NSCoding` protocol.

If you don't want to provide all properties in the `init` method you can use default values:

```
init(title : String? = nil, pageCount: Int? = nil){
  self.title = title
  self.pageCount = pageCount
}
```

Now you can just init your object without any properties. Like that `Book()`

Comment: I have major problem with this example, My object has too much property and now if every time i want to instance new object must init object with all property that is not nesesarry :|  @njuri

Comment: I want my new instance of object contains nil properties @njuri

Comment: Already using RMMAper in Objective C it was so easy for using but new is so complicated and not usable @njuri

Comment: Make your properties Optional if they aren't yet and profile default `nil` value to init method. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks but now when try to retrieve my object from userDefault i getting this error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value @njuri

Comment: You told that you'd like to properties to be `nil` - that's what the error tells you.

Comment: yes but when made new instance with nil properties i will set some values in properties and check my object when try to set in user default and it's correct but when try to retrieve it get the error @njuri

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solutions, you have to implement the two methods

Encode Method

```
func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)
```

Decoding method

```
 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

Complete Example code

```
class User: NSObject , NSCoding
{


var userID : Int = 0
var name : String = ""
var firstName : String = ""
var lastName : String = ""
var username : String = ""
var email : String = ""

override init(){
    super.init();
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {

    aCoder.encode(self.userID,  forKey: "id");
    aCoder.encode(self.firstName,    forKey: "first_name");
    aCoder.encode(self.lastName,    forKey: "last_name");
    aCoder.encode(self.name,    forKey: "name");
    aCoder.encode(self.username,forKey: "username");
    aCoder.encode(self.email,   forKey: "email");
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init()

    self.userID     = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "id");
    self.firstName  = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "first_name") as! String;
    self.lastName   = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "last_name") as! String;
    self.name       = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String
    self.username   = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "username") as! String
    self.email      = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "email") as! String;
}

init(data : [String: AnyObject]) {

    super.init()

    self.userID = String.numberValue(data["user_id"]).intValue;
    self.firstName = String.stringValue(data["first_name"]);
    self.lastName = String.stringValue(data["last_name"]);
    self.email = String.stringValue(data["email"]);
    self.username = String.stringValue(data["user_name"]);
}

class func loadLoggedInUser()  -> User {

    if let  archivedObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:"CurrentUserAcc"){

        if let user  = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: (archivedObject as! NSData) as Data) as? User {

            return user;
        }

    }

    return User()
}

func saveUser(){

    let archivedObject : NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self) as NSData

    UserDefaults.standard.set(archivedObject, forKey: "CurrentUserAcc");

    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();
}

func deleteUser(){

    UserDefaults.standard.set(nil, forKey: "CurrentUserAcc")

    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();
} 
}
```